# SSIS package inset header and detail

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

No   |  Name
121 | test1
245 | test3
546 | test4

I have got a text file same as above , i want to insert name and extension this file in to table1 after that i want insert contents file with id from table1 in to the table 2(like header and detail).
table1 and table2 have a relation with id.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_1
(
Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
filename varchar(50) NULL,
extention varchar(50) NULL
)  ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_2
(
Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
Table1_Id int ,
No varchar(50) NULL,
name varchar(50) NULL
)  ON [PRIMARY]
```

I want use SSIS pakage.how to do that? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you have multiple file at one location but format is same for all file and file name is different.

1)  Use ForEatch Loop Editor ---
Collection >> Enumerator chose Foreach File Enumerator and Specify folder location >> File type *.txt

Variable Mapping  >> Chose your local variable like (filename) and Index set 0

Add control inside foreach container

2)  Use Execute SQL Task Editor and insert record into table_1 and set @Identity value into new variable call ‘ID’ ( Which generate from table_1)
3)  Now you have ID column of Table_1 you can insert that value in Table_2
4)  Use Derived Column and Add additional column for table_2 is call ‘ID’

let me know if you need more clarification